# Why my Angular 5 application not work with deep linking?

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-web-app-service, angular5, deep-linking

I'm developing one Angular 5 application deployed on *Azure App Service*. My problem is that when I try to access with a direct link my application redirect me to home page.

These are my application routes:

```
// Imports
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // declaratins
  ],
  imports: [
    // modules
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
]),
    // modues
  ],
  providers: [
    // Imports
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've followed the [deployment angular's instruction](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) changing the *web.config* with following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I navigate inside application I can view the URL change correctly but if I try navigate directly a link like https://host/search I will redirect to https://host/home.

How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is the action rewrites to /index.html where it should rewrite to just /.

You can take a look at the web config here: [Web.config for hosting an Angular application on Azure Web App](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/06/web-config-for-hosting-an-angular-application-on-azure-web-app/)

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the late response. Glad that you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Ciao,

I've found the problem. @Martin Brandl answer is correct and useful but in my case the problem was that inside my **app.component** there was inside the *onOnInit* one redirect to Home Page.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
}
```

Thanks